# No overload for 'method' matches delegate 'RoutedEventHandler'

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have tried looking at questions similar to this for an answer but they seem to differ slightly, mind is 'RoutedEventHandler' while other questions are about just 'eventhandler' and don't really seem to match with my problem.

To help you understand, Im making a basic wpf c# TCP client that sends a message (what is in a textbox) while reading off the stream for a message back, then placing it into a text file.

This error occurs when trying to compile.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;

namespace client
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // Ip and port variables used for connect and gui display
        string ipaddress = "127.0.0.1";
        int port = 8888;

        /// <summary>
        /// Set new TCP client, stream writer and reader, connect and gui show ip and port
        /// </summary>
        public void MainWindow_Connect(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient(); // New TcpClient
            client.Connect(ipaddress, port); // IP, Port to connect        
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream()); // New StreamWriter instance
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(client.GetStream()); // New StreamReader instance
            // Interface label show ip and port
            serverip_lbl.Content = ipaddress;
            portno_lbl.Content = port;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Send message inside message_txt textbox, write to network stream and send
        /// </summary>
        private void send_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e, StreamWriter sw)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(message_txt.Text);
            sw.Flush();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Read from message from the server, write to textfile
        /// </summary>
        public void serverStream(StreamReader sr)
        {
            // Create a string array
            string[] message = { "\n", sr.ReadToEnd() };
            // WriteAllLines creates a file, writes a collection of strings to the file and then closes the file
            File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\Public\Documents\Messages.txt", message);
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="client.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:client"
    Loaded = "MainWindow_Connect"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="400">
<Grid>
    <Label x:Name="titleclient_txt" Content="Client" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="18.667" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontStyle="Italic" d:IsLocked="True"/>
    <Label x:Name="demotitle_txt" Content="Sending a message" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,50,87,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" d:IsLocked="True"/>
    <Label x:Name="server_lbl" Content="Server IP:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="74,106,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" d:IsLocked="True"/>
    <Label x:Name="serverip_lbl" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="155,106,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
    <Label x:Name="port_lbl" Content="Port:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="74,146,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" d:IsLocked="True"/>
    <Label x:Name="portno_lbl" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="155,146,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
    <Label x:Name="message_lbl" Content="Message:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="74,199,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" d:IsLocked="True"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="message_txt" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="70" Margin="74,230,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250"/>
    <Button x:Name="send_button" Content="Send" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="155,344,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="send_button_Click"/>

</Grid>
```

Comment: What is this code supposed to do?  Your Connect() method doesn't actually do anything, since the two `StreamWriter`s and the TcpClient will all be garbage collected after the method is finished, since you aren't keeping a reference to them.

Comment: Establish the connection to the server and make the gui labels show the ip and port in use.

Comment: Also there is no need to post the mainwindow.g.i.cs code, since that is designer generated code that shouldn't be modified anyway.

Comment: Okay thanks i'll edit it

Comment: It creates a TcpClient and then immediately disconnects after the Connect method ends.  You have to keep a reference to the TcpClient somewhere or it will be garbage collected.

Comment: Ah yes i see, could i fix this by placing the tcpclient and client.connect, then streamwriter and reader outside in the mainwindow class?

Comment: Yes that would prevent them from being garbage collected.  However you should really read some tutorials about c# programming and network communication before trying to write a program on your own.

Comment: You seem very new to c#

Comment: I haven't much experience with c# programming your right, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

Your send_button_Click method must have the same signature as the RoutedEventHandler. But yours has an additional StreamWriter argument which must be removed.

Comment: Can it also have the streamwriter argument to make them the same? Without the streamwriter argument the sw variable gives an error saying 'the name sw does not exist in the current context'?

Comment: Just define StreamWriter sw in your MainWindow class where you have your ip and port variables. The initialisation should of course stay in the Connect method, but just becomes sw = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());